# Broadcast Receiver not receive anything in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, broadcastreceiver

I would like to do is when the user onbackpress that new activity, I would like to update the alarm list in that fragment. But in my attempt when I use Broadcast receiver it does not receive anything. How to fix that?

**in the Alarm Activity**

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Log.d("test1","test R1");
        Intent intent = new Intent("on_alarm_remove");
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(ctx).sendBroadcast(intent);
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

**in the Alarm tab Fragment**

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ctx = getActivity();

        intentFilter = new IntentFilter("on_alarm_remove");
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(ctx).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver, intentFilter);
}

private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.d("test1","test R");
            db.removeRecord(db.getFirstAlarm().alarm_id);
            reloadFragment();
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        if (mMessageReceiver != null)
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(ctx).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
        super.onPause();
    }
```

**In manifest**

```
<receiver android:name=".reminder.ReminderFrag$mMessageReceiver" />
```

It doesn't crash, but nothing happen, In the log "test R1" has run but "test R" does not. Thanks again for helping

**Update:**

I found the root cause of the problem , since I am opening a new activity on top of the fragment, it will call the onPause when the alarm is trigger and also unregister the listener.

How can I differenate when is the alarm trigger and when is the user change to other tab/ leaving the app?  Should I use ondetach ?

**Update2:**

Also, I tried to remove the unregister in onPause
but it crash and show

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
```

Comment: You should register the receiver in `onResume()`

Comment: Thanks. How about onPause? How should I handle it

Comment: still the save java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState

Comment: Yes, you should unregister the receiver in `onPause()`.  Can you update your code to what you have now, and say what line the error is on and what error it is?

Comment: You also don't have to register a local `BroadcastReceiver` in the manifest.